# oracle sql from rows to columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write an Oracle SQL statement that convert table1 to table2

```
 number    name    
  1         A
  1         B
  2         A
  2         E
  3         D
```

```
number  name1   name2   name3   name4
  1      A      B       
  2      A      E   
  3      D
```

I tried to use listagg but this give me one column

Comment: Google: `Oracle pivot column`

Comment: please post what you tried. This does not seem to be standard pivot.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you're using dynamic SQL, you'd have to pre-define a number of columns.

If you're happy with 4, you could just join the table 4 times.

Or...

```
WITH rankedResults AS (
    SELECT
         number
        ,name1
        ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY number ORDER BY name1) as rank
    FROM table1
)
WITH diagonalResults (
    SELECT
         number
        ,CASE WHEN rank = 1 THEN name1 END AS name1
        ,CASE WHEN rank = 2 THEN name1 END AS name2
        ,CASE WHEN rank = 3 THEN name1 END AS name3
        ,CASE WHEN rank = 4 THEN name1 END AS name4
    FROM rankedResults
)
SELECT
     number
    ,MAX(name1) AS name1
    ,MAX(name2) AS name2
    ,MAX(name3) AS name3
    ,MAX(name4) AS name4
FROM diagonalResults
GROUP BY number
```

Comment: thanks, but Oracle pivot column helped a lot, and have better preformace